# Why do dynamically register broadcast receiver didn't work after reboot

Tags: android, service

I have a onBootCompleted broadcast receiver registered in the manifest. 
It runs starts MyService. My service in the onCreate registers 3 more broadcast receivers dynamically. 
The 3 new receivers filter on the following intent actions

- LOCALE_CHANGED,
- TIMEZONE_CHANGED and
- CONNECTIVITY_CHANGED.

These works correctly when I run the application from Eclipse but, after I reboot the device and my service starts up none of receivers work.

I have a work around implementation but, I would like to know why this is happening?

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<receiver android:name=".receiver.BootCompletedReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:stopWithTask="false" >
    </service>
```

Service:

```
public class MyService()
{
LocationTimeZoneC‌​hangedReceiver mLocationTimeZoneC‌​hangedReceiver = new LocationTimeZoneC‌​hangedReceiver()
NetworkChangedReceiver mNetworkChangedReceiver = new NetworkChangedReceiver()

public void onCreate()
{
  registerReceiver(mLocationTimeZoneChangedReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED));
  registerReceiver(mLocationTimeZoneC‌​hangedReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED));
  registerReceiver(mNetworkChangedReceiver, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
}
}
```

BootCompletedReceiver:

```
public class BootCompletedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){}
}
```

MyApplication:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application
{
     ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() { anonymous class...}

     public void onCreate()
     {
        bindService(new Intent(this, MyService.class), mServiceConnection,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
     }
}
```

Edited:
Edited code for Plinio.Santos.

It's a big app with many moving parts so at best I can post small code snippets.

Following are the steps I am following for testing:

- Push app via Eclipse,
- test that network change receiver is working
- leave wifi off
- Now restart the device
- wait for the process to start and turn on wifi.

Comment: does your service start these all 3 when rebooted?

Comment: Yes in the Service onCreate()
I had before implementing my workaround the following.

`registerReceiver(mLocationTimeZoneChangedReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED)); registerReceiver(mLocationTimeZoneChangedReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED));
registerReceiver(mNetworkChangedReceiver, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));`
I would turn on and off the wifi after restarting the device and not see any log from the connection change while my app process is running.

Comment: Reply to D_Vaibhav, I don't what the receivers to run when the application process is not running, and by registering them in the manifest, a wifi change will startup the whole application needlessly in some cases.

Comment: @TealFawn Ok. Got it !!

Comment: Did you add the android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED permission to manifest?

Comment: Boot complete works just fine it starts my service. The dynamically registered receivers are not working.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code (such as manifest, boot completed receiver and service class)? I have the same setup as you described and it's working properly.

Comment: Does BootCompletedReceiver bind or start the service?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the service is not started or bound due errors. Unfortunately I can not say it for sure without all binding/starting code.

Anyway, you can see bellow a code that worked fine after I rebooted (the app started, registered the receiver and is receiving the CONNECTIVITY_CHANGED broadcast.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<receiver android:name=".TestReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service
    android:name=".TestService"
    android:exported="true" />
```

Receiver class:

```
public class TestReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null && Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED receiverd !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            context.startService(new Intent(context, TestService.class));
        }
    }
}
```

Service class:

```
public class TestService extends Service {
    private BroadcastReceiver mConnectivityChangedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent != null && ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION receiverd !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        registerReceiver(mConnectivityChangedReceiver, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
    }
}
```